# Printing final elif statement in while loop

Tags: python

I created a simple program in Python where I use the random number module to generate a random number between 1 and 10 then ask the user to guess the number as shown here:

```
import random

randnum = random.randint(1, 10)

guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
guess = int(guess)

while guess != randnum:
    if guess < randnum:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
        guess = input("Guess again: ")
        guess = int(guess)
    elif guess > randnum:
        print("Your guess is too high")
        guess = input("Guess again: ")
        guess = int(guess)
    elif guess == randnum:
        print("That is correct!")
```

My problem is getting the program to print the final elif statement when they guess the correct number. Instead the while loop terminates because the conditions have been met. How do I print out the final statement when the correct number has been guessed?

Comment: Final elif will never execute inside while loop bcoz your while loop condition doesnot allow it to execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user gets it right, then `guess != randnum` will be false and the loop will exit before looking at any options.  Just move the last `elif` outside the loop:

```py
import random

randnum = random.randint(1, 10)

guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
guess = int(guess)

while guess != randnum:
    if guess < randnum:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
        guess = input("Guess again: ")
        guess = int(guess)
    elif guess > randnum:
        print("Your guess is too high")
        guess = input("Guess again: ")
        guess = int(guess)

print("That is correct!")
```

Although I would write code something more like this:

```py
import random

randnum = random.randint(1, 10)

guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))

while guess != randnum:
    if guess < randnum:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
    elif guess > randnum:
        print("Your guess is too high")
    
    guess = int(input("Guess again: "))

print("That is correct!")
```